# Easy way to add a zero to the filename if it need it

Tags: batch-rename

With big help from here, I have soon converted all my jpg files to gif (thanks again ALOT)

but when I was looking around at my files I have noticed that some folder I have added a zero to the filenames.

The filename standard I trying to have is 001.gif, 002.gif.... but some of the files have  01.gif, 02.gif and so on and that is not good for me.

So with the code, I got from convert that I find something that calls globe star I was ready to see if I can fix that for myself :)

but nothing happened when I run the code. Right now I just try to see if I can convert the file that has JPG

```
for f in /lib/**/*jpg; do
        if [ "${#f}" -eq 2 ]; then
    mv "$f" "0$f" 
    fi 
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to do this, but taking your attempt as a starting point

```
for f in /lib/**/[0-9][0-9].jpg; do
  b="${f##*/}"; d="${f%/*}"; 
  echo mv "$f" "${d}/0${b}"; 
done
```

That is, instead of matching all `jpg` files and then trying to test how many digits each has, just match the ones with exactly two leading digits. Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it's working correctly.

---

Alternatively you could something like this with the Perl-based `prename` command:

```
prename -n 's/(\d+)\./sprintf("%03d.",$1)/e' /lib/**/*.jpg
```

This takes any non-empty sequence of digits before a `.` and reprints them zero-padded to a minimum width of 3 digits.

Comment: Hmm very simple idea and I love it
But I have problem with the code, it add 0 at the beginner of the address and not the filename.

Comment: @Cazz apologies that was a dumb error on my part - please try it now

Comment: ohh no I have to thank you. it works fine and now I just have to understand why it works and I think I know why.